# How to select 700 random records from an access table?

Tags: c#, ms-access

This code give me the last 700 records, not 700 random records.

```
private string strsqlcommandBeta = " select top 700  LEFT(patronvalue17, INSTR(30, patronvalue17, ' ') -1) as patronvalue1,   Rnd([objectid]) AS Ran    from objectaer    " +
" order by objectdate desc" +
"  ";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not near MS Access, but give this a shot:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT top 700 LEFT(patronvalue17, INSTR(30, patronvalue17, ' ') -1) as patronvalue1, objectdate
    FROM objectaer
    ORDER BY Rnd([objectid]) ()
) order by objectdate desc
```

The Rnd([objectid])should give you a random number to sort by, then you sort by what you want after that.

Comment: ORDER BY Rnd([objectid]) 

it works great in my access app thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT top 700 LEFT(patronvalue17, INSTR(30, patronvalue17, ' ') -1) as patronvalue1, objectdate
    FROM objectaer
    ORDER BY newid()
) order by objectdate desc
```

The `newid()` function generates a random guid which can be used in order to sort the table, giving different results on every run. I don't know if you really need the outer select, it is used in order to sort the random items by date descending

Comment: You made the same mistake I made in my first answer, which JoelCoehoorn commented on.  This is for Access, not SQL SERVER